# Android (Milestone/Droid): View.OnKeyListener not working correctly?

Tags: android, listener, textview, milestone

I am using a simple `EditText` and register an `View.OnKeyListener`. Some GUI changes should happen (fading in/out of views) when certain conditions for the EditView text apply.
In the emulator, this works as expected. On the Motorola Droid/Milestone, the listener does not work, only

1. after pressing DEL, the listener is called the first time and always afterwards
2. when activating the number input, the listener works correctly

Note: I deactivated the suggestions with TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS and used the IME action  IME_ACTION_GO to have a workaround for this (otherwise the user could not "start" a request).

Comment: Same problem with xperia. Only DEL is sent to onKeyListener but rest of key strokes is directly modifying the text. If I change the keyboard to Hackers keyboard, situation is different. So I guess it has to do with the sony soft keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a better and working way to implement this: use `EditText.addTextChangedListener` with a `TextWatcher` class (and implement `TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`), works perfectly also on the Milestone/Droid.

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher cannot fully replace onKeyListener. For example, if your textbox is empty, how would you detect that user pressed DEL key? Or, what if you don't have textbox at all and you want to detect key events?